# Apache Ignite: caching ClusterGroup

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

I want to send message to server nodes. Is it correct to cache a `ClusterGroup`, i.e. what option is recommended:

1. `ignite.message(ignite.cluster().forServers()).send(...)`
2. `ignite.message(cachedCluster.forServers()).send(...)`
3. `ignite.message(cachedClusterGroup).send(...)`
4. `cachedMessaging.send(...)`

?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with any option you are comfortable with. You can easily check that: launch cluster of N nodes and check for the contents of these groups, make these two variables:

```
IgniteCluster cluster = ignite.cluster();
ClusterGroup clusterGroup = cluster.forServers();
```

After this, shutdown one node and check for the following:

```
ignite.cluster().forServers().nodes()
cluster.forServers().nodes()
clusterGroup.nodes()
```

Each of them will contain N-1 nodes listed in output, so you are good to go.