# Join on two Ignite Cluster is it possible?

Tags: ignite

In our Project  we are using Ignite and in it we have multiple Ignite cluster and we are using zookeeper Discovery, I wanted to know if Ignite supports Join on two different Ignite cluster if yes please share the approach.

Found few inputs on this but not that helpful.

1. [Apache Ignite: caching ClusterGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166433/apache-ignite-caching-clustergroup)
2. [Communication between two Ignite clusters (maybe merging two Ignite clusters in one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71440408/communication-between-two-ignite-clusters-maybe-merging-two-)    ignite-clusters-in

Comment: Different clusters means they are independent. If you join them it will be a single cluster, is not it? What's your goal?

Comment: Yes they are independent ,  the ask is to  join the result from one cluster with other based on some key, just like how a normal sql join works

Comment: Well, if they are two independent clusters, they are independent. If you want to perform a SQL over multiple nodes, they have to be in a single cluster. In other words, your scenario won't work. I still don't understand what your goal is. If you want to run a query over a large node set, just start how many nodes you need. 10 - fine, 100 - fine as well. Having two independent clusters makes sense if you want to have a master and a replica cluster, for example.

Comment: I suppose you might be misunderstanding the concept of a group of nodes that form a cluster vs multiple clusters. There is no upper limit of how many nodes you might have, i know some companies have hundreds of them, but it could be tricky in terms of maintenance and yes, most likely you will need to use Zookeper discovery.

Comment: If you indeed need to join some result from two independent clusters, you will need to do it manually. I.e. get a result from one, then from the second and do an aggregation/processing.

Comment: I'll rewrite it as an answer, since it looks like your question had been addressed. Feel free to mark it as helpful

Answer (score 1):

Well, if they are two independent clusters, they are independent. The most common scenario I can think of is - having a Master and Replica cluster with a synchronization in between.

If you want to perform a SQL over multiple nodes, they have to be in a single cluster. There is no hard limit on how many nodes you can have. I know that some companies have hundreds of nodes. But it could be tricky in terms of maintenance, like using Zookeeper discovery and paying a lot of attention to the network.

If you indeed need to join some result from two completely independent clusters, you will need to do it manually. I.e. get a result from one, then from the second and do an aggregation/processing.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [Change Data Capture] [1](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/change-data-capture) to copy key/value pairs from one cluster to another.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).